# Wordpress: Loop Help

Tags: loop, post-content

I was working on this site this morning and I ran into a bit of an issue with my static page.

I have a "featured" post section and I use:

```
<div id="featured">
    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/house.jpg" alt"Buy Me" />

    <div class="info">
     <?php query_posts(array ('tag'=> 'featured' )); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 

    </div>

</div>
```

The above works great, however, the page content is where I am running into an issue. I have a content section that is pulling in the "pages" actual content, and I use:

```
<div id="about">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>


        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2>Not Found</h2>

    <?php endif; ?>


</div>
```

When I refresh the page, both of the sections are now displaying the featured post, and not the the page content. Does anyone have a clue to why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `query_posts()` for your featured-post [custom loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query). As the Codex says: [**don't do that**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Not_for_Secondary_Loops).

The `query_posts()` function is intended to modify the **Primary Loop**. If you need a custom loop, use e.g. `$my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $args )`.

See here for [a good break-down of custom-loop options](http://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/).

Comment: Rarst has a good diagram here: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chip. I rewrote it after reading your reply as:

```
<?php $featured_query = new WP_Query( array ('tag'=> 'featured' ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php endwhile;?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Everything seems to be working just fine now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You should edit/update your original answer with this.

Comment: Glad to help! Just for future reference: given the way WPSE is intended to work, this would be better posted as an update to your answer, since it's not really a separate answer.

Comment: The ongoing updates should be added to a question, but a final working solution should be an answer and should be posted as such separately (obviously if it differs from other answers provided).